# How to show only the divs that meet all of the checkbox criteria?

Tags: jquery, html

With the example below, if you click on "magazine", the two "Magazine" divs appear, which is good!

However, when you then click on "$19.50", the two "Magazine" divs still appear, but now every div with "19" appears.

By clicking both "Magazine" and "$19.50", the end result should be the single "Magazine 19" div, if that makes sense. Thank you!

```js
$(":checkbox").click(function() {
    var re = new RegExp($(":checkbox:checked").map(function() {
        return this.value;
    }).get().join("|"));
    $(".product").each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this[re.source != "" && re.test($this.attr("class")) ? "show" : "hide"]();
    });
});
```

```css
#product {
  margin-top:40px;
}
.product {
  background:#ebeef2;
  padding:10px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  width:50%;
}
.filter-item {
  margin-right:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filter-category">
    <h2>Filter By Price</h2>
    <label for="filter-price" class="filter-item">$19.50
        <input type="checkbox" value="nineTeen" id="filter-price">
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
    <label for="filter-price" class="filter-item">$24.50
        <input type="checkbox" value="twentyFour" id="filter-price">
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
</div>

<div class="filter-category">
    <h2>Filter By Type</h2>
    <label for="filter-type" class="filter-item">Blog
        <input type="checkbox" value="blog" id="filter-type">
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
    <label for="filter-type" class="filter-item">Business
        <input type="checkbox" value="business" id="filter-type">
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
    <label for="filter-type" class="filter-item">Education
        <input type="checkbox" value="education" id="filter-type">
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
    <label for="filter-type" class="filter-item">Magazine
        <input type="checkbox" value="magazine" id="filter-type">
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
    <label for="filter-type" class="filter-item">Profile
        <input type="checkbox" value="profile" id="filter-type">
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
</div>

<div id="product">
    <div class="product education twentyFour">Education 24</div>
    <div class="product blog twentyFour">Blog 24</div>
    <div class="product business twentyFour">Business 24</div>
    <div class="product blog twentyFour">Blog 24</div>
    <div class="product business nineTeen">Business 19</div>
    <div class="product magazine nineTeen">Magazine 19</div>
    <div class="product magazine twentyFour">Magazine 24</div>
    <div class="product profile nineTeen">Profile 19</div>
    <div class="product blog twentyFour">Blog 24</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using an OR operation in the regex, so it match if at least one of the value is present. Even if you change the `.join("|")` to `.join(" ")`, it wouldn't work as the first checkboxes are for the price, and the classes in the product list does not begin with it.

You should keep your array of classes you are using to generate the regex, and use it to verify if all values in it are present in the product `class`. 
This may help you with that : [JQuery hasClass](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/)